# What does a "video system not initialised" error in pygame mean?

Tags: pygame, keyboard

I'm trying to play music when a key is pressed in pygame, then print a message.

When I run this script:

```
import pygame
import time

pressedkeys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

pygame.init()                      #initialize pygame
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048) # setup mixer to avoid sound lag

try:
    firstMusic = pygame.mixer.Sound("C:\(pathForMyMusicFile).wav")  #load sound
    secondMusic = pygame.mixer.Sound("C:\(pathForMy2ndMusicFile).wav")  #load sound

except:
    raise UserWarning, "could not load or play soundfiles"

if pressedkeys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
    firstMusic.play(-1)
    time.sleep(2)
```

I get this error:

> ```
> pressedkeys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
> pygame.error: video system not initialised
> Script terminated.
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Stani's Python Editor.

Comment: You should call `pre_init` before `init`.

Answer (score 1):

Random assumption since I've never used Pygame:

You can't receive/check keyboard events before initializing Pygame first. So move down your `pressedkeys = ...` line to be after `pygame.init()`?